# vscode import error: from scapy.all import IP

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scapy

vscode said can't find IP in scapy.all
[image]

but from terminal, i can import it:
[image]

could somebody tell my why?

Comment: Make sure you selected the appropriate interpreter environment in the extension for it to find the module.

Answer (score 6):

I get exactly the same issue with my Scapy code in VS Code. I think it's to do with the way pylint is working.

When you `from scapy.all import IP`, Python loads `scapy/all.py`, which includes the line `from scapy.layers.all import *`. `scapy/layers/all.py` includes this code:

```
for _l in conf.load_layers:
    log_loading.debug("Loading layer %s" % _l)
    try:
        load_layer(_l, globals_dict=globals(), symb_list=__all__)
    except Exception as e:
        log.warning("can't import layer %s: %s", _l, e)
```

`conf.load_layers` is over in `scapy/config.py`:

```
load_layers = ['bluetooth', 'bluetooth4LE', 'dhcp', 'dhcp6', 'dns',
               'dot11', 'dot15d4', 'eap', 'gprs', 'hsrp', 'inet',
               'inet6', 'ipsec', 'ir', 'isakmp', 'l2', 'l2tp',
               'llmnr', 'lltd', 'mgcp', 'mobileip', 'netbios',
               'netflow', 'ntp', 'ppp', 'pptp', 'radius', 'rip',
               'rtp', 'sctp', 'sixlowpan', 'skinny', 'smb', 'snmp',
               'tftp', 'vrrp', 'vxlan', 'x509', 'zigbee']
```

I suspect that pylint doesn't follow those imports correctly.

I've tried the workarounds suggested in the [relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/779), but they don't seem to fix anything for Scapy. Pylint eventually added [specific workarounds](https://github.com/PyCQA/astroid/pull/461) for the issues in Numpy - and no-one has done that for Scapy.

You can work around these issues by directly importing the `IP` class from the relevant layer at the top of your Python file:

```
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, UDP, TCP, ICMP
```

Et voila! No more pylint complaints about those imports.