# Unsolved Reference IP() and TCP() When Using Scapy

Tags: python-2.7, scapy

I copied the codes from the example to learn scapy. But realized the IDE showed the error with unsolved reference for IP() & TCP(). Anyone know how to fix this?

Here are the codes:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from scapy.all import *
import logging

logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)

dst_ip = "10.0.0.1"
src_port = RandShort()
dst_port=80

tcp_connect_scan_resp = sr1(IP(dst=dst_ip)/TCP(sport=src_port,dport=dst_port,flags="S"), timeout=10)
if(str(type(tcp_connect_scan_resp))==""):
    print("Closed")
elif(tcp_connect_scan_resp.haslayer(TCP)):
    if(tcp_connect_scan_resp.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x12):
        send_rst =sr(IP(dst=dst_ip)/TCP(sport=src_port,dport=dst_port,flags="AR"),timeout=10)
        print("Open")
elif (tcp_connect_scan_resp.getlayer(TCP).flags ==0x14):
    print("Closed")
```

I'm using Pycharm IDE. Python2.7 and scapy 2.4.0. I searched on stackoverflow and found someone asked the same question before but no answer.....
Here is the error after I tried to run the codes:

```
/Users/chenneyhuang/PycharmProjects/Scanner/venv/bin/python /Users/chenneyhuang/PycharmProjects/Scanner/TCP.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chenneyhuang/PycharmProjects/Scanner/TCP.py", line 12, in <module>
    tcp_connect_scan_resp = sr1(IP(dst=dst_ip)/TCP(sport=src_port,dport=dst_port,flags="S"), timeout=10)
  File "/Users/chenneyhuang/PycharmProjects/Scanner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 393, in sr1
    s=conf.L3socket(promisc=promisc, filter=filter, nofilter=nofilter, iface=iface)
  File "/Users/chenneyhuang/PycharmProjects/Scanner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/supersocket.py", line 58, in __init__
    (self.ins, self.dev_bpf) = get_dev_bpf()
  File "/Users/chenneyhuang/PycharmProjects/Scanner/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/core.py", line 98, in get_dev_bpf
    raise Scapy_Exception("No /dev/bpf handle is available !")
scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: No /dev/bpf handle is available !

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered the same **Unsolved Reference** issue last week here:
[vscode import error: from scapy.all import IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852412/vscode-import-error-from-scapy-all-import-ip/52032600#52032600)

In short, don't worry about that error, it's a limitation of Pylint (or similar). I propose a workaround in the other question, if you'd like to remove the error/warning.

For the `No /dev/bpf handle is available` error, have you tried running the script as root? I see that suggested as a solution over on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/1343

Comment: I'm able to run the codes if I run scapy as root.... but how to config with PyCharm.....I actually read the GitHub link u posted before. but don't know how to install the development in the specific environment for the project in PyCharm...