# VScode not recognizing certain functions from the Scapy module: how to fix?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, interpretation

note that I am coding in Python and using VScode as my editor.

I have imported the Scapy module for my code the following way:
`from scapy.all import *`.
The problem is that some of the functions that that are imported are marked as undefined.
[Error description popup that is displayed when hovering over a marked imported function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CISBe.png)
My question is, **how can I make VScode recognize these functions?**
So far, it only occurred for the functions from the layers class of Scapy (`scapy.layers`), but do bare in mind that other than these functions I am using only the `srp1` function, which is from another class.
The code does run perfectly when ran through VScode's terminal, so I have figured the problem must be related to the Python's IntelliSense that I am using.

I have checked that the selected Python interpreter in VScode is the same one as the one that its path is saved and used in the PATH environmental variable.
I have also tried importing directly from the layers class (`from scapy.layers.all import *`) but it also didn't seem to help.
Something that did work for me is replacing the `*` with the names of the functions that cause this problem, but I find this solution to be more messy and also impractical because there are quite a few function that should be listed there, and there would probably be more to add in the future.

Comment: This seems related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51852412/vscode-import-error-from-scapy-all-import-ip